# как работают смарт конракты в криптовалютах?

Tags: blockchain, криптография, smart-contract, web3.js

всем привет! Я новичок в теме криптовалюты и сейчас у меня стоит задача получить баланс заданных аккаунтов. Я выяснил, что для взаимодействия с сетями нужны ноды этих сетей, которые можно запускать самому или воспользоваться услугами разных блокчейн эксплореров. В итоге я понял как получать баланс по адресу, но я не понимаю, как получить баланс адреса в разных валютах. Например в сети bep-20 на аккаунт переводили валюты USDT, USDС и другие. Используя web3 js я получаю лишь общий баланс. Что этот баланс отражает?
количество bnb?то есть полученные валюты конвертируются в bnb?
как получить баланс, например, именно USDT?
в интернетах нашел примеры, где баланс получают используя адрес смарт контракта. Значит смарт контракт один и не создается для каждой транзакции?

Answer (score 1):

Что `bep-20`, что `erc-20` это смарт контракты на solidity, реализующие следующий интерфейс. Баланс всех владельцев токена хранится в одном смарт-контракте в огромном `mapping`. Посмотреть баланс можно через метод `balanceOf`

```
interface IERC20 {
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
    function transfer(address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
    function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
}
```

Посмотрите [этот репозиторий на GitHub](https://github.com/react-declarative/erc20-payment-gateway). Это платежный шлюз, позволяющий получать токены в качестве оплаты в смарт-контракте